# Are Q-learning agents required to converge towards actual state-action values?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

**It is my understanding that Q-learning attempts to find the actual state-action values for all states and actions. However, my hypothetical example below seems to indicate that this is not necessarily the case.**

Imagine a Markov decision process (MDP) with the following attributes:

- a state space `S = {s_1}` with only one possible state,
- an action space `A = {a_1}` with a singular possible action,
- a reward function `R: S X A X S → ℝ` with `R(s_1, a_1, s_1) = 4`
- and finally a state transition function `T: S X A X S → [0,1]` which produces probability 1 for all actions `A` and state transitions from and to state `s_1`

Now assume that we have a single agent which has been initialized using optimistic initialization. For all possible states and actions we set the Q-value equal to 5 (i.e. `Q(s_1, a_1) = 5`). Q-values will be updated using the Bellman equation:

`Q(S,A) := Q(S,A) + α( R + γQ(S',A') - Q(S,A) )`

Here α and γ are chosen such that `α = (0,1]` and `γ = (0,1]`. Notice that we will require α and γ to be non-zero.

When the agent selects its action (`a_1`) in state `s_1`, the update formula becomes:

`Q(s_1, a_1) := 5 + α( 4 + γ5 - 5 )`

Notice that the Q-value does not change when `γ5 = 1`, or more generally when `γQ(S,A) = Q(S,A) - R`. Also, the Q-value will increase when `γQ(S,A) > Q(S,A) - R`, which would further increase the difference between the actual state-action value and the expected state-action value.

This seems to indicate that in some cases, it is possible for the difference between the actual and expected state-action values to increase over time. In other words, it is possible for the expected value to diverge from the actual value.

If we were to initialize the Q-values to equal 0 for all states and actions, we surely would not end up in this  situation. However, I do believe it possible that a stochastic reward/transition function may cause the agent to over estimate its state-action values in a similar fashion, causing the above behavior to take effect. This would require a highly improbable situation where the MDP transitions to a high payoff state often, even though this transition has a very low likelihood.

Perhaps there are any assumptions I made here that actually do not hold. Maybe the target goal is not to precisely estimate the true state-action value, but rather that convergence to optimal state-action values is sufficient. That being said, I do find it rather odd that the divergence behavior between actual and expected returns is possible.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above assumption is that I expected `Q(s,a)` to converge to `R(s,a,s')`. This is not the case. As described in the RL book by Sutton and Barto:

`Q(s,a) = sum_r p(s',r|s,a)*r = E[r]`

The Q-values, in this case, actually represent the expected one-step reward and should converge to `R + γQ(S',A')` and not R(s,a,s'). It is therefore unsurprising that the state-action values can move away from the deterministic immediate reward `R` and that the value at which `Q(s,a)` converges is dependent on `γ`.

Furthermore, the hypothetical situation where `Q(s,a)` is overestimated when using a stochastic reward/transition function is possible. Convergence to the actual state-action values is only guaranteed when all state-action pairs `(s,a)` are visited an infinite amount of times. Therefore, this is an issue related to exploration and exploitation. (In this case, the agent should have been allowed to explore more.)